# Tumblr Home Page feed

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, tumblr

I am trying to fetch Tumblr home page feed in iOS using Tumblr V2 API's.
Here is my code for the fetch feed:

```
-(void)requestFeed
{
OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:kTumblrConsumerKey
                                                secret:kTumblrConsumerSecret];

TumblrUser *tumblrUser = [Utils currentUser];
NSString *username = (tumblrUser!=nil)?tumblrUser.username:@"";
NSString *requestUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/%@/posts/queue", username];

OAToken *authToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithUserDefaultsUsingServiceProviderName:kTumblrAccessTokenDefaultsKey prefix:@"TumblrConnect"];


OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl]
                                                               consumer:consumer
                                                                  token:authToken
                                                                  realm:nil   // our service provider doesn't specify a realm
                                                      signatureProvider:nil]; // use the default method, HMAC-SHA1
[consumer release];
[authToken release];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];



OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(FeedTicket:didFinishWithData:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(FeedTicket:didFailWithError:)];
}
```

But i am getting below error in response.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"
>   UserInfo=0x8a995a0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/coocku/posts/queue,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/coocku/posts/queue,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x8c997c0
>   "unsupported URL"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add url scheme to your url

e.g.

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/%@/posts/queue];
```

OR

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/%@/posts/queue];
```

Comment: Thanks @Sunny, but we have to use it as `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/%@/posts/queue",username]];`
But it didn't worked..:(

Comment: Here is a change in error now i am getting this error:
`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x8a51be0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/coocku/posts/queue, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/coocku/posts/queue, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0x8ba1e90 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."}`